# NgRx Data DefaultDataServiceConfig

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-ngrx-data

I just started to use **NgRx Data** on my project and I'm searching for a couple of hours and I can't find a solution for a problem that I'm facing with.

I'm trying to change the default root of calls by using **DefaultDataServiceConfig** like that:

**app.module.ts**

```
export const defaultDataServiceConfig: DefaultDataServiceConfig = {
  root: `${environment.apiUrl}/`,
};

@NgModel({
   ...
   providers: [
      {
         provide: DefaultDataServiceConfig
         useValue: defaultDataServiceConfig
      }
   ]
});
```

**environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
   ...
   apiUrl: 'https://my-api.com/v1',
};
```

However, the call is going to **localhost** `http://localhost:3000/client/list` instead of going to **my-api.com** `https://my-api.com/v1/client/list`.

Is there something that I'm missing? I can't find any examples and **ngrx.io** documentation is a poor one.

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same problem.

Check the [DefaultDataService Doc](https://ngrx.io/api/data/DefaultDataService), the 4th argument in its constructor is optional and **undefined** by default. When you extend this class creating your own service pass the config argument like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class EmployersDataService extends DefaultDataService<Employer> {
  constructor(
    http: HttpClient,
    httpUrlGenerator: HttpUrlGenerator,
    config: DefaultDataServiceConfig
  ) {
    super('Employer', http, httpUrlGenerator, config);
  }
}
```

Then, the DefaultDataServiceConfig provided in app.module.ts will work.

Comment: Works perfect!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You should import it on the same level where you import EntityDataModule

```js
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        DataComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        EntityDataModule.forRoot(entityConfig)
    ],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: DefaultDataServiceConfig,
            useValue: {
                root: environment.apiUrl,
            },
        }
    ],
    exports: [
        DataComponent,
    ],
})
```

If for whatever reason it doesn't work for you - you can provide your own `HttpUrlGenerator`, it resolves urls for every entity.

```js
export abstract class HttpUrlGenerator {
  abstract entityResource(entityName: string, root: string): string;

  abstract collectionResource(entityName: string, root: string): string;

  abstract registerHttpResourceUrls(
    entityHttpResourceUrls?: EntityHttpResourceUrls
  ): void;
}
```

Comment: With HttpUrlGenerator is working as expected, but when I'm trying to use DefaultDataServiceConfig in app.module, the changes are not applied and I can't find out why. I'm trying to set DefaultDataServiceConfig because I don't want to set this in every service.

Comment: I've tested it yesterday on a brand new angular 9 ngrx data 9 project and `DefaultDataServiceConfig` worked. That's why I assumed that import is wrong. Do you have other plugins that use ngrx/data? maybe one of them overrides the setting. As an option - put a breakpoint in HttpUrlGenerator` to see stack trace to find which data was injected to the service. Perhaps it brings light on the source of the problem.